# WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am using below code to launch android driver. But I am getting error at the time of launching the driver.
On line:

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(appiumServiceUrl), capabilities);
```

Complete Code:

```
public class Test {

protected static AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
private AppiumDriverLocalService appiumService;
private String appiumServiceUrl;
Properties prop = new Properties();

@org.testng.annotations.Test
public void testappiumdriver() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    appiumService = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
    appiumService.start();
    appiumServiceUrl = appiumService.getUrl().toString();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("device_capabilities.properties"));
    Map<String, String> prop_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String key : prop.stringPropertyNames()) {
        prop_map.put(key, prop.getProperty(key));
    }           
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(prop_map);
    driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(appiumServiceUrl), capabilities);
}

}
```

Error:

> FAILED: testappiumdriver
>       org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient,
>   InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
>       Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
>       System info: host: 'PSL-GGN-597', ip: '192.168.2.137', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_91'
>       Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>         at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:195)
>         at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:209)
>         at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
>         at 
>         io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>         at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>         at 
>           org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver. 
>          (RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
>         at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver. 
>          (DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:84)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:94)
>         at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:93)
>         at test.Test.testappiumdriver(Test.java:37)

I am using below jars in my project:

selenium-java 3.13
selenium-server 3.13
java-client 6.1.0

I have also tried with different version of selenium and java-client but again getting same error.

Comment: please post the log few lines before the error occur.

Answer (score 1):

****Solution 1st****

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "xyz");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", Platform.ANDROID);
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.hp.HPSupportAssistant");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.hp.HPSupportAssistant.MainActivity");
     capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 6000);    capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS,true);
    //desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
```

*Here comment below line and then run it will work*

```
desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
```

*solution 2nd 
Or keep above line in desired capabilities but before that do
run 3 cmd on cmd promt*

```
adb shell pm list packages -f > D://t.txt
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test

desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
```

Comment: Solution 1st is tried and tested for me. It works. The issue happens when we are not defining the App package and App Activity while configuring the desired capability.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible 
 Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z' 
 System info: host: 'PSL-GGN-597', ip: '192.168.2.137', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91' 
 Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
```

...implies that the **AndroidDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_91** which is pretty **ancient**.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u191**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.